# How to setup Icecast to hear stream on my local network?

Tags: networking, streaming, icecast

i want to setup icecast to hear the stream in my local network with a link like this "http://192.168.1.10:8000/stream"

How do i setup icecast to do this? i am using Windows 7

Currently i can hear the stream with "127.0.0.1:8000/stream"

Answer (score 0):

Open your Firewall.

Make sure you are using the correct IP address for that machine.

That's it, as the stream seems to be working on localhost already.

Comment: Thank you. i must use the ip from my Router. 192.168.1.2 then it works fine.